# How to pass Data from Parent Form to Child Form

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 forms, Form1 is a parent form and Form2 is a child form. Both of them are set to show at the same time.....Form1's mid-container is set to true and has a button, Form2 has a text-box...I want it that if I press the button in Form1 something will appear in the text-box in Form2

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    IsMdiContainer = True
    Dim inv As New Form2
    inv.MdiParent = Me
    inv.Show()
    inv.Location = New Point(15, 15)

End Sub
```

I tried clicking the button but nothing happened, I also tried the other way around...putting a button in Form2 and a text-box in Form1 and it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to move the `inv` variable out of the form_load scope

```
Public Class Form1

Private inv As New Form2 'here

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    IsMdiContainer = True

    inv.MdiParent = Me
    inv.Show()
    inv.Location = New Point(15, 15)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    inv.TextBox1.Text = "Hello World"
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a TextBox1 control on Form2 and a button on Form1 and upon clicking button on Form1, "Hello World" will appear on TextBox1 on Form2, just do it like this...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.TextBox1.Text="Hello World"
End Sub
```

Comment: That was the problem...I did the same but when I clicked the button nothing happens......I tried It again but this I put the button in Form2 and the text-box in Form1 and it worked...but the one I want is for Form1 to pass data to Form2 but not Form2 to Form1